# Get Checkbox Values as soon as entered and put into PHP variable

Tags: php, html

New to PHP here! I have this form. It consists of three dropdown menus. The first menu has its options from a SQL query. The other two are just HTML. We are also using Bootstrap Multiselect so on screen it appears as 3 dropdown menus with checkboxes within. We also have a submit button which reveals the checkboxes that has been checked. This is the code I have:

```
<form id="numberOrderForm" method="POST">
    <div class="wrappers" id="multi-select1Wrapper">
        <h2>Area Code</h2>
        <select class="dropDownMenus" id="multi-select1" name="multi_select1[]" multiple="multiple" action="index.php">
            <?php
                //The query asking from our database
                $areaCodeSQL = "SELECT ac.Number AS `AreaCode`, ac.Name AS `AreaName`
                                FROM `AreaCodes` ac";                                                               //SQL query: From the table 'AreaCodes' select 'Number' and put into 'AreaCode', select Name and put into 'AreaName'

                $areaCodeResults = $conn->query($areaCodeSQL);                                                      // put results of SQL query into this variable

                if ($areaCodeResults->num_rows > 0) {                                                               // if num_rows(from $results) is greater than 0, then do this:
                    // output data of each row
                                foreach($areaCodeResults as $areaCodeResult)                                        //for each item in $areCodeResults do this:
                                    {
                                        $areaNameAndCode =  $areaCodeResult['AreaCode'] ." ". $areaCodeResult['AreaName'];  //get AreaCode and AreaName from query result and concat them
                                        $areaName = $areaCodeResult['AreaName'];                                    // get AreaName
                                        $areaCode = $areaCodeResult['AreaCode'];                                    //get AreaCode

                                        ?><option class="menuoption1" name="menuAreaCode" value="<?php echo $areaCode ?>"  ><?php echo $areaNameAndCode; ?></option><?php  //Create this option element populated with query result variables
                                    }
                } 

            ?>
        </select>
    </div>       

    <div class="wrappers" id="multi-select2Wrapper">
        <h2>Number Type</h2>
        <select class="dropDownMenus" id="multi-select2" name="multi_select2[]" multiple="multiple" action="index.php">
            <option class="menuoption2" value="gold">Gold</option>
            <option class="menuoption2" value="silver">Silver</option>
            <option class="menuoption2" value="bronze">Bronze</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="wrappers" id="multi-select3Wrapper">
        <h2>Order</h2>
        <select class="dropDownMenus" id="multi-select3" name="multi_select3[]" action="index.php">
            <option class="menuoption3" value="sequential">Sequential</option>
            <option class="menuoption3" value="random">Random</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="submitButtonWrapper" class="dropDownMenus">
        <button id="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
    </div>
</form> 

<div id="showResults1"><!--test div to show contents of $_POST['multi-select1'] -->
    <?php 
        $areaCode = isset($_POST['multi_select1']) ? $_POST['multi_select1'] : []; // This is an if/else statement written in shorthand
        var_dump($areaCode) 
    ?>
</div> 

<div id="showResults2"><!--test div to show contents of $_POST['multi-select2'] -->
    <?php 
        $numberType = isset($_POST['multi_select2']) ? $_POST['multi_select2'] : []; // This is an if/else statement written in shorthand
        var_dump($numberType) 
    ?>
</div> 

<div id="showResults2"><!--test div to show contents of $_POST['multi-select3'] -->
    <?php 
        $order = isset($_POST['multi_select3']) ? $_POST['multi_select3'] : []; // This is an if/else statement written in shorthand
        var_dump($order) 
    ?>
</div>
```

But now I want to achieve a similar result WITHOUT a `<submit>` button. I still want whats checked by the user but to have it instantly upon being checked to be on show in `<div>` elements underneath. I have also to use only PHP and have those values in a PHP variable at the end. Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to use AJAX, not possible with just PHP

Comment: This is what I intially thought, but my tutor insists it can be done. I have been trying to find a solution for a while, and AJAX always comes up when I research it. Yet this I cannot do as stated by my brief :/

Comment: PHP is s server side script. It can't do anything until the client sends a request to the server. The only way to send a request is via either the submit button, or by some other page event triggering a Javascript function which sends the request (either by submitting the form, or sending an AJAX request). If your tutor has a means of doing it with just PHP, I'd love to know what it is :)

Comment: You either use AJAX/XMLHttpRequest or populate the div using javascript and listen to the onchange callback. PHP needs a request from the user and that cannot be achieved without submitting a form or sending an ajax reuqest